# Pass flags to xargs

Tags: bash, sudo, kill, xargs

I want to kill a bunch of processes using this command:

```
sudo ps ax | grep node | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

But it gives me operation not permitted even with sudo.

Then I tried with `kill -9` individually for each process and it worked.

Now my question is how do I pass `-9` flag to kill via xargs?

Nether  `xargs kill -9` or  `xargs -9 kill` worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the first command in that pipeline (`ps ax`) is being run as root.  The remainder of the line (including the `kill` command) is being run as your normal non-root user.

To run the `kill` as root, you'd need to run it like this:

```
ps ax | grep node | awk '{print $1}' | sudo xargs kill -9
```

or

```
ps ax | grep node | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

alternatively, if you have `pkill` installed, you could run:

```
sudo pkill -9 node
```

Comment: `pkill` is awesome! It's available for Mac via Homebrew

Comment: The equivalent (to search on the whole command line) would be `pkill -f -9 node`.

Answer (score 1):

You need the sudo on the kill.

`ps ax | grep node | awk '{print $1}' | xargs sudo kill -9`